# Android mocking new object null pointer exception

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, android-testing

I have the following unit test:

```html
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) @PrepareForTest(StripeRequest.class)
public class StripePresenterTest {

  @Rule TrampolineSchedulerRule trampolineSchedulerRule = new TrampolineSchedulerRule();

  @Mock UserRepository userRepository;
  @Mock CustomersRepository customersRepository;
  @Mock StripePresenter.View view;

  private StripePresenter presenter;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
presenter = new StripePresenter(userRepository, customersRepository);
presenter.setView(view);
  }

  @Test public void shouldSaveTokenFromPaymentMethod() {
    // Given
    PaymentMethod paymentMethod = new PaymentMethod();
    StripeRequest stripeRequest = new StripeRequest("tokenId");

    // When
    Mockito.when(customersRepository.addCreditCard(1, stripeRequest)).thenReturn(Single.just(paymentMethod));
    presenter.addCreditCard(1, "tokenId");

    // Then
    Mockito.verify(view).onTokenSavedOnServerFromPaymentMethod(paymentMethod);
  }
```

I have the following code in presenter:

```html
  public void addCreditCard(int customerId, String tokenId) {
    disposables = RxUtil.initDisposables(disposables);

    StripeRequest stripeRequest = new StripeRequest(tokenId);

    Disposable disposable = customersRepository.addCreditCard(customerId, stripeRequest)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            paymentMethod ->
                view.onTokenSavedOnServerFromPaymentMethod(paymentMethod),
            view::handleError
        );

    disposables.add(disposable);
  }
```

But I am getting this error:

```html
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.anstar.presentation.agreements.payment.StripePresenter.addCreditCard(StripePresenter.java:75)
 at com.anstar.presentation.payments.StripePresenterTest.shouldSave(StripePresenterTest.java:63)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$LastRuleTestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
 at com.anstar.presentation.core.TrampolineSchedulerRule$1.evaluate(TrampolineSchedulerRule.java:21)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:91)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
 at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Did you override `equals()` correctly in your StripeRequest class?

Comment: I have not override that at all. What I should do?

Comment: When you call Mockito.when, you can mock a function call of a mocked object. Mockito uses `equals()` on the parameters you pass to the function you want to mock to check what the mock should return. Since the base implementation of equals() is a simple check for reference equality, you need to override equals() in your StripeRequest class, as the StripeRequest you create in your test is a different object than the one that the presenter creates. 
Just override equals() in StripeRequest and return `obj instanceof StripeRequest && ((StripeRequest) obj).tokenId.equals(this.tokenId)`